# setState in react js, with ES6 destructuring

Tags: reactjs

I have this react code which set the state::

```
onMoveUp={(ids: SelectedIdMap) => {
              this.setState({
                xyz: {
                  ...this.state.xyz,
                  [tt]: [
                    ...this.state.xyz[tt].filter(a => (a.id in ids)),
                    ...this.state.xyz[tt].filter(a => !(a.id in ids)),
                  ],
                },
              });
            }}
```

This code changes the index of passed array element (ids) to the top of array.

Current state is like this::

```
{"51f6c052-b218-45ce-b3db-c9b95249e03a":[{"id":"11553dc4-d194-476c-9e05-aaac28ea3e76","prediction":"India–Japan relations","confidence":1},{"id":"3f76ce1d-a821-4418-a332-3285176ae456","prediction":"Japan Democratic Party (1954) politicians","confidence":1},{"id":"031d3913-984a-4af7-aaa3-73e23c206ff1","prediction":"Japan–Taiwan relations","confidence":1}]}
```

I am unable to understand what **[tt]** means in this code & how it is updated.

```
ids = 11553dc4-d194-476c-9e05-aaac28ea3e76 in the parameter.
```

It is silly question but please help me understand it.

Comment: `[tt]` means "an object key set to the value of the variable named `tt`". The code you provided does not show where `tt` is defined, presumably it's somewhere else in that file

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing but `Computed property name` concept in `js`. That means we can use any valid js expression to compute the property name at run time.

As per [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets [], that will be computed and used as the property name.
>   This is reminiscent of the bracket notation of the property accessor
>   syntax.

Its helpful to write a reusable code instead of hardcoding the values.

Check this snippet:

```js
var obj = {"1234": 1, "3412": 2},
  a = "34", b = "12";

var newObj = {
  [a+b]: obj[a+b],
  [b+a]: obj[b+a],
  [10+20+30]: 60
}

console.log('newObj = ', newObj);
```

Check this snippet how its working in your case:

```js
var obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2};

function update(key, value){
   return {[key]: value};
}

obj = Object.assign({}, obj, update('a', 10));
obj = Object.assign({}, obj, update('b', 20));

console.log('bj = ', obj);
```